# Memory card is not visible

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, crashes, zip

I was zipping a file on the memory card, but the process of zipping hangs, then the whole Android phone hangs, and I had to remove the battery. Now the memory card is not visible, I tried it on any other phone and there is the same problem.

Comment: Have you initialized the SD-card as portable storage or internal storage? If you have initialized it as portable storage try to read the card in an USB SD-card reader on a PC. If that does not work most likely the SD-card is defect and has to be replaced.

Comment: @Robert  An error while zipping the file appears to cause the memory card to be unrecognizable to any device. "If that does not work most likely the SD-card is defect and has to be replaced" It's hard to believe, but it seems like it just happened.

Comment: It is hard to believe because you have reversed cause and effect. The SD-card broke, therefore the ZIP operation hung (card does not answer on commands from phone), not the other way around. But as I wrote this is just a guess. The only reliable way to prove it is using a PC + USB SD-Card reader. Try to read the card and if this works try re-partition and re-format the SD-card.